# Adding CC and BCC address in email box -PHP mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to add cc and bcc recipient to my php script using the php mailer but its not working.Nothing changes still the same,
[Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA1nX.png)

I want it to show something like the image above. These are my codes

```
$mail->isSMTP();  
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';                                    // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mail.xxx.xxx.xx';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('prigovori@xxx.xxx.xx', 'SOME ADDRESS');
    $mail->addAddress($someMail); /// Add a recipient

    $mail->addReplyTo('prigovori@xxx.xxx.xx');
    //CC and BCC
    $mail->addCC("cc@example.com");  
    $mail->addBCC("bcc@example.com");


    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'EMAIL SUBJECT';
    $mail->Body    =   '<h2 style="margin-bottom: 30px;color: black;">Some title</h2>
                        <div style="height: auto;display:block;margin-bottom: 20px;background-color: white;">
                            <p style="color: black;">Here is some email text</p>
                        </div>';




    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
```

Comment: Do the calls to `addCC` and `addBCC` return `true`? Can you show the SMTP transcript with`SMTPDebug = 2`.

Comment: What do you mean that nothing changes ?  And the purpose of the BCC is that the recipient will not see it.

Comment: @Synchro, sure, let  me try it out by debugging

Comment: @RohitGupta, Check the image , that's what i want it to show,

Comment: @The bcc isnt an issue, i understand , but the CC should show up

Comment: @Synchro, please check here, https://anotepad.com/notes/kbnqh3c2

Comment: The purpose of the image is obvious.  But you still have not clarified what the code does now.  Am I supposed to get it all working at my site to help you ?????

Comment: @RohitGupta, the code is sending emails and i want to see the Cc receipient to in the mail box headers like that of the image,, it doesnt show, i know cc recipient is showed in the mail box too but mine not working sir,

Comment: @RohitGupta, yes pls if only with php mailer, i don't know if i should add the cc recipient in header so the mailbox will capture it , have done all too, didn't work

Comment: No, you have to make the effort.  Dont use an image.  Type in what you are seeing now and then what you want to see.  You have already spent more time than that and lost a day.

Comment: @ omh, i have stayed on this for whole month, doing all the research, couldn't find any answer to this to fix in my code, I watched a video on youtube and they did use headers but its not working for me when i tried it,  I never even knew there was a forum like this until my homie told me to check stack, and its wasn't even easy over here , i couldn't put a question on this platform , got lot of declines . Please kindly assist me .

Comment: I'm not a big fun of asking questions I mostly read documentations all the time.

Comment: Looking at that SMTP transcript, you can see there is only occurrence of `RCPT TO`; there should be one of those for each distinct To, CC and BCC address. I would still like to see the results of the call to `addCC`. Also note that if the CC address is already used in a To address, it won't be added because that would make no difference in who the message is sent to.

Comment: oh ok, i think thats what i did, used the same email for cc, let me change and see